# addClass("test") doesn't work - but css("background","red") does

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Anyone know why?

Here's the JS:

```
$(".screenshots .tab1").hover(function() {
    $(".section1").addClass("test");
        }, function() {
    $(".section1").removeClass("test");
        });
    });
```

And the CSS:

```
.test {
    background: black;
    border: 1px solid #ffb75b;
    background-color: #fffadb;
    }
```

Comment: are you sure that css is correct? I'm not sure `background: black` is valid, especially since you're then setting `background-color`. If you manually add the class to the html does the css apply?

Comment: What exactly *does not work*?

Comment: `background: black` is correct. It's just not a very good practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe there is a css entry that overrules yours. Try this:

```
background-color: #fffadb !important;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is just a copy and paste error but you have a `});` to much. Should be:

```
$(".screenshots .tab1").hover(function() {
    $(".section1").addClass("test");
}, function() {
    $(".section1").removeClass("test");
});
```

See a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/wmD4E/

Of course `background: black` will have no effect because `background-color: #fffadb;` overwrites it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you have an extra  });  at the end of your JS code.
 see working example here  http://jsbin.com/adeye4/edit

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying background once:

```
.test {
    border: 1px solid #ffb75b;
    background-color: #fffadb;
}
```